# limit maximum WordPress menu depth in customize

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to limit the menu depth in wp-admin/customize.php?

I found the variable wpNavMenu.options.menuItemDepthPerLevel in the wp-admin/js/customize-nav-menus.js file, but I have no idea if changing this variable would work, or even how to access it.

Comment: Welcome! Why not just create the menus with the depth you want? What are you trying to avoid - a specific menu showing too many items? Also, **do not update core files ever**. If you have access to the code, you could also change the `depth` parameter of the `wp_nav_menu` or create a custom nav walker.

Comment: I am looking for a solution similar to this one, only mine should be for the customize. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242068/how-to-limit-wordpress-menu-depth-in-admin-panel

Comment: You can certainly create your own setting for the theme customizer, however, you'll have to edit the code that outputs the nav menu to read your customizer setting. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API#Adding_a_New_Setting

Comment: I just need to modify the JavaScript for the user interface such that customize won't allow the user to create multilevel sub-menus in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that core ever intended to restrict the number of menu items that can be added in the backend, but as @disinfor mentioned, you can set the `depth` parameter of `wp_nav_menu()` to limit the output.

Comment: I want to limit navigation sub-menu depth, but I don't want to remove the menu items on lower depths, which is what wp_nav_menu() does with the 'depth' argument.

Comment: Oh, so unlimited depth, but limited number of sub menu items per level?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know I can create a custom walker for my menu, but the user experience is going to be weird.

Comment: Yeah, but I think a custom walker is the only option. Some JS might be doable for the backend, but idk for sure.

Comment: If it's doable for the admin panel (see the solution provided here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242068/how-to-limit-wordpress-menu-depth-in-admin-panel ), then surely it must be duable for customize, too. Oh well, I'll figure it out on my own.